# How to capture the click plus drag event

Tags: javascript

I want to capture the click plus drag event like browser text selection, what I did is calling the ondrag event:

```js
function drag() {
  console.log("being dragged.");
}
```

```html
<p ondrag="drag()" > Hello World!</p>
```

But it's not being called when I click and drag text, any idea why?

Comment: if you don't want the actual drag and drop api, just register mousemove when mousedown is triggered, then remove it on mouseup.

Comment: @rlemon  I think ur solution is doable, can u share ur code if you don't mind
?

Comment: I edited my answer, now that I realize you don't want drag events, you actually want mousemove events :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't actually want to use drag events, and that you want to use mousemove events. Something like this will do the trick:

```js
var p = document.querySelector('p');

p.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownListener, true);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpListener, true);

function mouseMoveListener(e) {
  console.log('moving mouse');
}

function mouseDownListener(e) {
  console.log('mouse down');
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener, true);
}

function mouseUpListener(e) {
  console.log('mouse up');
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveListener, true);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add draggable= "true" attribute to p tag to make it work

check this link for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

```js
   function drag() {
       console.log("being dragged.");
    }
```

```html
    <p ondrag="drag()" draggable="true"> Hello World!</p>
```

codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/KGZoRm

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is I don't want the text position to be moved, I just want to capture the mouse down+ dragging process.